# Is it possible to have a linear transformation from a complex vector space to a real one?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, definition

I know that a Linear Transformation, T is a function ( mapping ) from a vector space X to another vector space Y, with the linearity property - 
T(a.x + b.y) = a.T(x) + b.T(y) ;
where 'a' and 'b' are scalars.

Suppose X and Y are complex and real vector spaces respectively.
Since X is a complex vector space 'a' and 'b' may be imaginary. So, a.T(x) will not be defined, for T(x) is an element of Y, which is a real vector space ( whose field of scalars is the set of real numbers ).

Using the above reasoning, I suppose that such a linear transformation is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more a question of not making sense. A linear transformation is a special kind of function from a vector space over a field into another vector space over the *same* field.

Comment: So, whenever we talk about a linear transformation, is it implicitly assumed that the scalar fields are the same?

Comment: @ShashankKumar, yes. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map.

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes, the scalar field of the second vector space is larger that the one of the first one, but it's easy to see that there's no problem there.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So, is the concept of Linear Transformation loosely defined, then? Or is left for the context to decide whether the domain and co-domain can have the same scalar field or not?

Comment: @ShashankKumar No, it is not loosely defined at all. Every respectable Linear Algebra textbook will tell you that you are using twice the same filed of scaler. Se page 127 of [this book](https://books.google.pt/books?id=czDdnZPBFHcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=linear+transformation&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVl7CYkeDbAhVLWsAKHRjZA3IQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20transformation&f=false), for instance.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Then, this means that for the special case specified by you in your previous comment, such an LT would simply be a function and not an LT, because it violates the definition. If such instances are sometimes allowed, then this would mean the definition has a loophole.

Comment: @ShashankKumar No. It just means that sometimes people relax a little. Note that in every case that I am aware of, whenever an author writes about linear maps from a real vector space into a complex one, he or she always adds that we are forgeting the complex structure on the second vector space and that we are seeing it as a real vector space.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, I have understood. Thanks.

Comment: @ShashankKumar I'm glad I could help.